# Connect to Google Cloud Endpoints from an Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently refactoring a web-app from Angular 1 to Angular 2, but I am having difficulties finding any examples connecting to Google Cloud Endpoints from an Angular 2 app.

I used the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create the Angular 2 application. I want to use the endpoints api from a couple of different services, so it would be preferable if any suggested answer takes this into account.

**In Angular 1 I did the following**

In my index.html:

```
    <script>
        function init() {
            console.log("Initializing Cloud Endpoints..");
            window.init();
        };
    </script>        

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

and in my main.js:

```
function Main($scope, $window){
    var vm = this;

    $window.init= function() {
        $scope.$apply(vm.loadApi);
    };

    vm.loadApi = function(){
        gapi.client.load('deviceStockApi', 'v1', function(){

            console.log("Cloud Endpoints are now available");

        }, 'https://name-of-my-endpoints-app.appspot.com/_ah/api');
    }
}
```

**In Angular 2 I have tried**

**Edit1:** I should note that I am just trying to get the api to load for starters. This is why I have put all the code in the index.html file in the example below. However, optimally, I would prefer a solution with a best practice for initiating and using the Cloud Endpoints from an Angular 2 app.

In my index.html:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>

<script>
  function init() {
    console.log("Init called");

    gapi.client.load('deviceStockApi', 'v1', function(){
      console.log("Cloud Endpoints are now available");
    }, 'https://name-of-my-endpoints-app.appspot.com/_ah/api');
  }
</script>
```

When I run the webapp, the init function is not called (no console output). However, it seems like the script is loaded.

[image]

Any suggestions for how to fix this is appreciated! Also, if anyone has found some documentation from Google or others elaborating on this, please share!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reversing the order of your operations here? Like you did for Angular 1, try moving the apis.google.com import below the init codeblock.